# Why I am not getting any output?

Tags: javascript

```
function printManyTimes(str) {
       var sentence = str + "is cool"
           for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i += 2) {
               console.log(sentence);
}

printManyTimes("Satyam")
}
```

I am not getting any output. Result is blank, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: your closing brace for function is misplaced.

Comment: Possibly because your code is not valid, there seems to be a missing brace, or maybe the code above is mis-formatted?

Answer (score 1):

If you indent your code correctly, you see, that you call the function *inside* itself, not after it:

```js
function printManyTimes(str) {
    var sentence = str + "is cool"
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i += 2) {
        console.log(sentence);
    }
    printManyTimes("Satyam")
}
```

So, it won't run at all - and if you would try it, you would get *a lot* of logs printed in the console, and a stack overflow (not the site) error.

It should be like that:

```js
function printManyTimes(str) {
    var sentence = str + "is cool"
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i += 2) {
        console.log(sentence);
    }
}

printManyTimes("Satyam")
```

Answer (score 0):

the second closing bracket is after the function call - technically you defined a recursive function.

You forgot to close bracket of for cycle.